# How to detect swipe gestures on the screen and pass them to a small ViewPager at the bottom?

Tags: android

I have implemented a small `ViewPager` above the button in the lower half of the screen. What is above it, is a `FrameLayout` that is used as a camera preview.
The view pager has the camera modes. I am after the iOS Camera effect in an Android Application.

What I need is for the swipe gestures left-right to be caught in the `FrameLayout` and sent to the `ViewPager` in order to swipe its pages left-right. At the moment the user can change modes by swiping on the `ViewPager` itself, but I want to enable them to swipe on the whole screen and get the same effect. How do I do that

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some code from another stackoverflow question about detecting left and right swipe gesture and adapted it to my use case, by adding some more code. Here is the final result:

```
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;

public void onCreate(...) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureListenerImpl());
}

relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

private class GestureListenerImpl extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(isRightToLeftSwipe(e1, e2, velocityX)) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return false;
        }  else if (isLeftToRightSwipe(e1, e2, velocityX)) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isRightToLeftSwipe(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX) {
    return e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
            Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;
}

private boolean isLeftToRightSwipe(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX) {
    return e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
            Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;
}
```